# How to cross compile solaris 32-bit

Tags: go, gcc, cross-compiling, solaris

We are currently building our Go executables for several platforms including Solaris 64-bit. We have requests for a 32-bit Solaris executable version as well and I am unable to get this to work (the person who setup the Solaris 64-bit cross compiler is gone and unreachable).

I tried just setting -m32 flag on *go build* using our existing solaris cross compilation, but that didn't work, so I am attempting to build a Solaris 32-bit specific cross compiler.

I googled and found some vague examples, so I am following this process:

1. Copy headers and libraries from a 32-bit Solaris machine to my Linux build machine.
2. D/L and build binutils and gcc pointing SYSROOT to the downloaded 32-bit Solaris headers and libraries where:

$TARGET=sparc-sun-solaris2.10

$SYSROOT=*/path/to/solaris32/includes*

$PREFIX=*/path/to/gcc-output*

`binutils-2.31/configure -target=$TARGET --prefix=$PREFIX -with-sysroot=$SYSROOT -v`

```
gcc-8.2.0/configure --target=$TARGET --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld  --prefix=$PREFIX -with-sysroot=$SYSROOT --disable-libgcj --enable-languages=c,c++,go -v
```

3. Create a symlink to gogcc and put GCC on the path
4. Compile a trivial test go program like this:

   `go build --compiler gccgo --gccgoflags "-m32 -O3 -static-libgo -Wl,-dy -lnsl -lsocket -lrt -lsendfile" -o ${GOTOOLS}/${BINARIES}/${PROJECT_NAME}/test/solaris_sparc32 test/main.go`

This fails as follows:

go build: when using gccgo toolchain, please pass compiler flags using -gccgoflags, not -gcflags

command-line-arguments

**gccgo: error: may not use both -m32 and -m64**

Clearly I don't know what I'm doing. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Given you're getting `gccgo: error: may not use both -m32 and -m64` for an error message, I suspect you're somehow still getting `-m64` as a command-line argument from somewhere.

Comment: It seems likely that the `go build` command is including the `-m64` flag since go only supports that architecture on Solaris.

Comment: @maerics Thinking about this, I'm at the point where I'm wondering at the *why* behind this customer request.  Given the posted target must be 64-bit - Solaris 10 SPARC - the reason for the request is probably, umm, *interesting*.  And if that `-m64` is coming from the `go build` command somewhere, trying to override it is really getting into unsupported hacks.  It should work if forced and the source is clean and portable - highly likely given the plethora of platforms supported - but there's still a chance for a significant bug. I wouldn't want to be on the hook for supporting that.

Comment: @AndrewHenle heh, _interesting_ indeed =P

Answer (score 5):

Solaris 32-bit does not appear to be supported, according to [the list of supported OS/arch targets](https://golang.org/doc/install/source#environment):

> The valid combinations of $GOOS and $GOARCH are:
>
> ```
> $GOOS     $GOARCH
> ...
> solaris   amd64
> ...
> ```

That is, Solaris 64-bit is explicitly listed as a supported platform but Solaris 32-bit is *not* listed.

As such, there is good reason to believe that go programs will *not* run reliably on Solaris 32-bit systems and you probably should not agree to support that platform (if you do happen to get that cross compilation working) mainly because the go team itself does not support it!

Comment: 64-bit Solaris can still run 32-bit executables.  In fact, many if not most of the system utilities such as `mv` and `cp` are still 32-bit on a 64-bit installation.

Comment: My point is that the official go documentation explicitly includes solaris/64 but not solaris/32.

Comment: Given the error message the OP posted, that point hasn't been reached yet.  Although I will admit I'm at a loss to come up with a reason a 32-bit Solaris build is even necessary given the platform is Solaris 10. Solaris 10 always supported 64-bit and by now still-alive 32-bit hardware is just about unheard of.

Comment: And I just noticed the target is SPARC.  I'm all but certain that Solaris 10 can't even run on 32-bit SPARC CPUs.

Comment: Correct, Solaris 10 only includes a 64-bit kernel for SPARC, not 32-bit.  (Solaris 10 still included a 32-bit kernel for x86 alongside the then-new 64-bit x86 kernel,  Solaris 11 dropped the 32-bit x86 kernel to go 64-bit only as well.)